# From inside the docker container i want to copy the file in to the host machine

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker container that basically runs a jar and creates an output json file. Is there any way i can copy this file into a folder in the docker host before the docker run exits ? .I have tried the below approach and it works fine.

```
docker run image1
docker cp <container id>:<path in container> <host file path>
```

Above command copies the file from the container to the docker host. However for this to work i have to ensure that the container doesn't exit in the mean time (by using a sleep in the program thats run in the jar). So a better approach will be to actually copy the file into the host from within the container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best decision is to have shared volume for container:

```
docker run -v /volume/on/your/host/machine:/volume/on/container image1
```

You can read more here https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/

Comment: Great! That worked. I had to put my jar file and other resources in that volume path in the host just in case someone doesnt note that. Thank you very much.